# EC2 Public IPv4 DNS how to disable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-ec2-instance-connect

I am able to access my website contents from the Public IPv4 DNS of the EC2 instance as well as my domain and this is creating an issue on google with duplicate content. How do I disable the Public IPv4 DNS which looks like (ec2-5-89-19-335.ca-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com)-→ this is just and example URL or how do I stop any content to display from Public IPv4 DNS?

Answer (score 4):

You can disable the public DNS name by switching off `enableDnsHostnames`: [DNS Support in your VPC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-dns.html#vpc-dns-support)

Comment: The problem with this approach, however, is that queries to the private hosted route53 domain (attached to the VPC) are not resolved anymore...

These DNS queries only work when both "enableDnsHostnames" and "enableDnsSupport" are enabled as stated in the AWS message when adding a VPC to a private hosted domain in route53.